# How to update a value in a nested hash given path in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

Given path as an array `str_arr=["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, a value `x=456` and a hash `h={"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>123}}}}` update hash with value `x`. So after update it should be `{"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>456}}}}`. Length of array is variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use an Array to access nested Hash keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773296/use-an-array-to-access-nested-hash-keys)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method for this purpose:

```
h.dig(*str_arr[0..-2])[str_arr.last] = x
# => 456
h
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>456}}}}
```

Comment: ok it works for ruby 2.3+ any way to do the same with ruby 2.1.4 ? @Marek

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain ruby solution since you asked for ruby 2.1.4

```rb
str_arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
h = {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>123}}}}
x = 456

update_nested_hash(h, str_arr, x)
print h # {"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>456}}}}

def update_nested_hash(h, str_arr, x)
  a = str_arr.shift
  return h[a] = x if str_arr.empty?
  h[a][update_nested_hash(h[a], str_arr, x)]
end
```